# Does "Don't stick your foot/shoe in the wall" fit this context?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say there is a guy who is standing next to a wall with his leg half bent backwards and pressed against the  wall. I want to tell him to stop doing it as I am worried about the appearance of the wall

Can I say

> Stop sticking your foot in the wall, it is spoiling it.

I am not sure about the verb 'stick' as it is seemingly used for pointed or similar objects. Is this expression correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three problems:

1. You can't stick your foot *in* a wall unless it has a hole.
2. Changing *in* to *on*, we naturally want a different verb than *stick*, like *put*.
3. I don't think I'd personally talk about *spoiling* a wall; I might say something like "you're getting it dirty".

If their foot's still on the wall, I think I'd say something like this:

> Could you please get your foot off the wall?  You're getting it dirty.

If it's not on the wall anymore, or if they're a repeat offender, I might say this:

> Could you stop putting your foot on the wall?  You're getting it dirty.

I usually try to make requests like this more polite by adding "could you" and "please".  I also tend to insert concessive modifiers, because I don't want to be quite so confrontational: I often say things like "You're [kind of] getting it dirty" or "You're getting it [a little bit] dirty".  They don't really add any meaning, but they soften the blow a little by weakening the statement at the end.

Comment: If the idea is that he is putting is foot through the wall, i.e. making a hole, then "stick" is correct. But as the poster here says, if the idea is that he is resting his shoe against the wall, perhaps leaving footprints on the wall, then "stick" is not really appropriate. It would be more natural to say "Stop putting your foot against the wall" or "Stop putting your foot on the wall".

Comment: @Jay I just want to make sure we're in agreement.  The original post says "pressed against the wall", so that is the context I answered in.

Comment: I'd actually say "Please *take* your foot off the wall" (rather than *get*), but otherwise, this is spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

Although verb *put* might be slightly better, the verb *stick* (or participle *sticking*) is not so much a problem as is preposition *in*.  *On* or *against* would be better.

> Stop putting your foot against the wall, you're spoiling it.
>   Stop putting your foot there, you're spoiling the wall.

The second form avoids an ambiguous *it*.  In the second form, *sticking* could reasonably replace *putting*.

Comment: Agree with jwpat7 -> Stop putting your foot against the wall. You are spoiling it. I don't have points to upvote :(